# VirtoCommerce thumbnails not found in Azure

Tags: azure, virtocommerce

I've deployed VirtoCommerce 1.13 from source code to Azure and i'm getting problems with the thumbnails.

Url.ImageThumbnail(foo) in the item view is returning the url to the *.thumb.* image, but it doesn't exist.

The main image is being saved to storage and the thumbnails are saved as metadata, but the frontend is trying to get the thumb for the image as a image file that doesn't exists.

What i'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Is that issue appears with every image you try to upload to blob storage? We had an issue if generated thumb image was more than 8Kb size. That was fixed but there were no releases with that fix. [Here is the fix commit change](https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-community/tree/2e7551e93d3d6bf12d8bc25ea359a681955a57e5)

Comment: Yes, it's with every image even after applying the 8Kb fix.

Answer (score -1):

The image is typically automatically created by blobstorage provider. I would however suggest using 2.0 version instead of 1.13 as it includes many more features and is the latest one.

Comment: The problem is that the thumb image is not being created, the storage folder only contains the original images and the url in the UI get's me to an 404 error, "BlobNotFound".